# Mathematics in Football- Foul play and goal-scoring opportunity

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I am reading an article talking about the mathematics in football (link: https://plus.maths.org/content/ball ). In the second part, it asks if a player should risk being sent off in order to gain the opportunity of having a goal, providing that a foul will not lead to penalty kick.

I am not sure about what the writer talks about in the following part, especially the notation of 'crossover time'. Would someone help out me in understanding the writer's claim?

> We need to know how likely it is that a goal will be scored if the
>   offence is not committed. This will seldom be an easy judgement to
>   make, but it is crucial to making the right decision. That decision
>   can be neatly described by identifying a crossover time, T,
>   corresponding to the particular chance that a goal will result. A
>   player should risk a red card if, and only if, the crucial moment
>   arises at time T or later. For games at a good professional level, a
>   snapshot of the values is
>
> Chance of a Goal --- Crossover Time
>
> $100\% $  --- 16 minutes
>
> $60\% $ --- 48 minutes
>
> $30\% $ --- 71 minutes
>
> Recall that this table applies when a "professional
>   foul" would not lead to a penalty kick. Even the best players stumble,
>   or mis-hit their shots, so the chance of a goal will only rarely be
>   close to $100\%$. A player who gets sent off in these circumstances
>   before half-time is likely to have made a miscalculation! On the other
>   hand, very late in a tight game, the table suggests that if an
>   attacker has a non-negligible chance of scoring, doing the nasty deed
>   may be best for your team. As a football enthusiast, I dislike this
>   implication of the table. But it suggests the desirability of changing
>   the rules of soccer to encourage fair play: permit a referee to award
>   a penalty kick (or even a goal) if a defender is sent off in these
>   circumstances, wherever the crime is committed!

Comment: By crossover time the author simply means the time when the benefit of the foul (large chance of scoring a goal) outweighs the cost (chance of conceding a goal if the player is sent off).

Comment: @IanF1 : then the table means if i have 16 minutes left, i should risk a little bit as i have 100% chance of getting a goal??

Comment: No. It means that if committing a foul would mean a 100% chance of scoring a goal, it is worthwhile any time after the 16th minute - this is the crossover time when the cost of being sent off is less than the benefit of a definite goal. Similarly if there's only a 30% chance of the foul resulting in a goal, it's not worth getting sent off until the 71st minute when the cost is only 19 minutes of being a man down.